# In C# mongodb, match the entire external List of Objects to the Child list of the Parent list

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

`Suppose, I've User list with list of order

**User model**

```
`public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}`
```

*User Order model*

```
`public class UserOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}`
```

**Order model**

```
`public class Order
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}`
```

Here, I want to retrieve all user list that contain all element of List in UserOrder list. (Compare with Name and Price)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean, do you want to include the current Orders list when querying User?

You need to link the two tables. For example, add a field `UserId` to the `UserOrder` model to associate with `User`; or add a `List<int>` to the `User` model to store the corresponding `UserOrderId`.

I made a simple test, you can refer to it. In order to facilitate maintenance, I will write the method of processing data from the database in a separate service:

User Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> UserOrderIds { get; set; }
    public List<UserOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

UserService:

```
public class UserService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<User> _users;
        public UserService(IUserDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _users = database.GetCollection<User>(settings.UserCollectionName);
        }
        public async Task<List<User>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _users.Find(s => true).ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<User> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _users.Find<User>(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        public async Task<User> CreateAsync(User user)
        {
            await _users.InsertOneAsync(user);
            return user;
        }
        public async Task UpdateAsync(int id, User user)
        {
            await _users.ReplaceOneAsync(s => s.Id == id, user);
        }
        public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            await _users.DeleteOneAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

UserOrderService:

```
public class UserOrderService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<UserOrder> _userOrders;
        public UserOrderService(IUserDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _userOrders = database.GetCollection<UserOrder>(settings.UserOrderCollectionName);
        }
        public async Task<List<UserOrder>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _userOrders.Find(s => true).ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<UserOrder> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _userOrders.Find<UserOrder>(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        public async Task<UserOrder> CreateAsync(UserOrder userOrder)
        {
            await _userOrders.InsertOneAsync(userOrder);
            return userOrder;
        }
        public async Task UpdateAsync(int id, UserOrder userOrder)
        {
            await _userOrders.ReplaceOneAsync(c => c.Id == id, userOrder);
        }
        public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            await _userOrders.DeleteOneAsync(c => c.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

appsetting.json:

```
"UserDatabaseSettings": {
    "UserCollectionName": "User",
    "UserOrderCollectionName": "UserOrder",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "TestDb"
  }
```

IUserDatabaseSettings(Used to obtain database related information):

```
public interface IUserDatabaseSettings
{
    string UserCollectionName { get; set; }
    string UserOrderCollectionName { get; set; }
    string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
public class UserDatabaseSettings : IUserDatabaseSettings
{
    public string UserCollectionName { get; set; }
    public string UserOrderCollectionName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Registration service:

```
services.Configure<UserDatabaseSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(UserDatabaseSettings)));

services.AddSingleton<IUserDatabaseSettings>(provider =>
                provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<UserDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
services.AddSingleton<UserOrderService>();
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserService _userService;
        private readonly UserOrderService _userOrderService;

        public UserController(UserService sService, UserOrderService cService)
        {
            _userService = sService;
            _userOrderService = cService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetAll()
        {
            var users = await _userService.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(users);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetById(int id)
        {
            var user = await _userService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (user.UserOrderIds.Count > 0)
            {
                var tempList = new List<UserOrder>();
                foreach (var userOrderId in user.UserOrderIds)
                {
                    var userOrder = await _userOrderService.GetByIdAsync(userOrderId);
                    if (userOrder != null)
                        tempList.Add(userOrder);
                }
                user.Orders = tempList;
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(User user)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            await _userService.CreateAsync(user);
            return Ok(user);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, User updatedUser)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var queriedStudent = await _userService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (queriedStudent == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await _userService.UpdateAsync(id, updatedUser);

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var student = await _userService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await _userService.DeleteAsync(id);

            return NoContent();
        }
    }
```

Test Result:

[image]

[Complete example](https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/getting-started-aspnetcore-mongodb) is here.